# Common steps to promote a web-site for devices reviews?

Tags: seo, website-promotion

There is a web-site, that contains reviews of computers, software etc.

How to promote it ?

I have several ideas:

1. Answering questions, people asking on, say, Google Answers, Yahoo Answers etc.
2. I have a bunch of video, that i've uploaded to YouTube and some other hostings.

These methods requires a lot of routine work. I've thinking about link-markets, but did't tried they yet. It is a good way ?

I've also have questions about search engines:

Question 1: Will i penalized by search engine, when i set the same description for video on several hostings ? Or i need to rephrase every description for the same video ?

Question 2: In description for video, say, in YouTube, i cannot place a link, but can write it in plain text, like www.example.com. Will it handled by SE as an actual link ?

Question 3: In every description for video, i write in plain text: "go to www.example.com" for more information. Will it have some positive or negative impact on my ranking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to promote it ?
>
> I have several ideas:
>
> Answering questions, people asking on,
>   say, Google Answers, Yahoo Answers
>   etc.
>
> I have a bunch of video, that i've
>   uploaded to YouTube and some other
>   hostings.
>
> These methods requires a lot of
>   routine work. I've thinking about
>   link-markets, but did't tried they
>   yet. It is a good way ?

Those sound like good ways to promote it. Don't forget using Twitter to announce each review as I am sure people interested in that kind of stuff are monitoring it looking for new content. A Facebook page is probably mandatory at this point in time. Twitter, Stumbleupon, and Dzone and other voting links/counters are also an easy way to let your users promote your content for you.

> Question 1: Will i penalized by search
>   engine, when i set the same
>   description for video on several
>   hostings ? Or i need to rephrase every
>   description for the same video ?

Since they are not on your site you won't be penalized. The other pages *may* run afoul of duplicate content issues but I doubt it since there's probably other content on the page to help reduce the risk. But if you want to be absolutely sure change each description around a little bit. Just enough so they're different.

> Question 2: In description for video,
>   say, in YouTube, i cannot place a
>   link, but can write it in plain text,
>   like www.example.com. Will it handled
>   by SE as an actual link ?

No. But think outside of the box. There's more to the world then SEO. If someone visits your site because they found your URL with that video then it was worth it.

> Question 3: In every description for
>   video, i write in plain text: "go to
>   www.example.com" for more information.
>   Will it have some positive or negative
>   impact on my ranking ?

No impact since they are not links. But it is still good for marketing purposes.